# Android: How to user service with right way?

Tags: android, service

I have a service, when activity started I do bind to service with following way:

```
bindService(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

this way correct?

I need service will start when application started and live in background mode always. 
If user manually stopped application in settings then when application started again service need start, too.

And I need don't create service if it is already exists(already running in background mode). Have a right way bind to existing service?

Anybody know how to can I do this with right way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Just Start a Unbounded Service like**

```
startService(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

**2.And For Automatic restart of your Service when killed by OS**

in your `onStartCommand()` return `START_STICKY`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**3.And For setting Button stop**

in your `onDestroy()` of Service again start the Service like

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
        // starting the service when the service is destroyed.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
        startService(intent);
        super.onDestroy();

};
```

**NOTE:Service will stopped if you FORCE_STOP your app in Settings**

Comment: When I call startService this method? in application class or in activity?

Comment: No Problem to start anyWhere.thats based on your requirement

Comment: If I call startService method in every activity and new service created again?

Comment: @mr.boyfox no..only one service will run..oonstatCommand() execute for every time.

Comment: @mr.boyfox fisst start the sevice and bind whenever your Actvity launches